# Finding a location of a word in python

Tags: python

Say I have this code

```
text=['Whatsapp app open']
    
def check(i,text):
    if i!=-1:
        return i

res=[]
for t in text:
    i=t.find('app')
    f=check(i,t)
    res.append(t[0:f])

print(res)
```

I want the output to be `Whatsapp` and not only `Whats`. Is there any function which finds the entire string as a whole and returns the index so that I can print `Whatsapp` instead of `Whats`?

Comment: `f+=len('app')`?

Comment: did you consider regluar expressions? https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: This works but is very case specific. Say in my other example I have the text as "Instagram app open", then this logic wont work.. :(

Comment: Is there always a space before that `app` string you're matching? In that case, `i=t.find(' app')` might do the trick.

Comment: just consider lst.split("") to split the list into words. s.strip() to remove the whitespaces. And s.index('pattern') to get the location

Comment: you should rather split to list of words and later use `for`-loop to check `if "app" in word:`

Answer (score 0):

You should split text to list of words and use `for`-loop to check `if "app" in word:`

```
sentences = ['Whatsapp app open', 'Instagram app open']
    
for text in sentences:
    res = []

    for word in text.split(' '):
        #if 'app' in word.lower():
        if 'app' in word:
            res.append(word)

    print(text, res)
```

Result:

```
Whatsapp app open ['Whatsapp', 'app']
Instagram app open ['app']
```

The same as list comprehension

```
for text in sentences:
    
    res = [word for word in text.split(' ') if 'app' in word]

    print(text, res)
```

---

Or you should use `regex`

```
import re

sentences = ['Whatsapp app open', 'Instagram app open']

for text in sentences:
    
    res = re.findall('[^ ]*app[^ ]*', text)

    print(text, res)
```

---

For something more complex you may need `Natural Language Processing` - ie. module [nltk](https://nltk.org)